# How to insert data into SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, insert, int

I have code like this:

```
con.Open();

cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Penawaran (ID_Paket,Jenis_Paket,Harga_Paket) Values (@ID_Paket,@Jenis_Paket,@Harga_Paket", con);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_Paket", txtIDPaket.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Jenis_Paket", txtjenisPaket.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Harga_Paket", txtHargaPaket.Value); // this is int sir how to insert it, still error i write like this

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Please help me to inside int to my table `Paket`.

Comment: Can you post the error you get?

Comment: You might want to read [this](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and replace the calls to `AddWithValue(name,value)` with `Add(name, sqlDbType).Value = value`.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a *missing parenthesis* at the end of `Insert` query

```sql
 INSERT INTO Penawaran (ID_Paket,Jenis_Paket,Harga_Paket)
               VALUES (@ID_Paket,@Jenis_Paket,@Harga_Paket) --Here
```

Comment: Oh my god i forget to change it, Thanks sir :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
           SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Penawaran (ID_Paket,Jenis_Paket,Harga_Paket) Values (@ID_Paket,@Jenis_Paket,@Harga_Paket", con));
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID_Paket", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Jenis_Paket", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Harga_Paket", SqlDbType.VarChar); // this is int sir how to insert it, still error i write like this

            cmd.Parameters["@ID_Paket"] = int.Parse(txtIDPaket.Text);
            cmd.Parameters["@Jenis_Paket"] = txtjenisPaket.Text;
            cmd.Parameters["@Harga_Paket"]  = txtHargaPaket.Value; // this is int sir how to insert it, still error i write like this
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
```

Comment: Your third line is missing the closing paranthesis after the value - as the OP did :-)